# Is the begining of the sentence with the zero article correct?

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article, zero-article

Can I use the zero article before `Video` in the following sentence? If yes, then why.

> Video baby monitor is also great for prevention from sudden infant
>   death syndrome (SIDS).

Comment: Note that you should write "prevention of" here, not "prevention from".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you can't.

If you're talking about video baby monitors in general, you can say:

- A video baby monitor is also great for prevention of sudden infant death syndrome (SIDS), *or*
- Video baby monitors are also great for prevention of sudden infant death syndrome (SIDS).

If you're talking about a specific video baby monitor or about a specific type or model of video baby monitor, you can say:

- The video baby monitor is also great for prevention of sudden infant death syndrome (SIDS), *or*
- This video baby monitor is also great for prevention of sudden infant death syndrome (SIDS).

If it's a product sold as "Video Baby Monitor", you could write it without an article:

- Video Baby Monitor is also great for prevention of sudden infant death syndrome (SIDS).

Comment: Digital encryption transmission will provide safe and private service of this device.  - so in this sentence should also be the definite article?

Comment: No, it is correct because the transmission is uncountable word ;) I guess

Comment: True - although if it's for an article and follows on from previous sentences about the device, I would be more likely to begin the sentence with the words "Its digitally encrypted transmissions" (or "Their" if the previous sentence had been worded in the plural).  If it's for a technical specification or bullet points or advertising copy then "Digitally encrypted transmission" is fine.

Comment: You should know that advertising copy and bullet lists are often _telegraphic_, meaning they leave out words that are required in Standard Written English.  They are also often trying to be "hip" rather than "correct."  Don't take them as a guideline for the Right Thing.